# c++ for each full cycle

Tags: visual-c++, iterator

i have a vector:

```
vector<Player> players;
players.push_back(Player(20000));
players.push_back(Player(10000));
players.push_back(Player(12000));
players.push_back(Player(32000));
players.push_back(Player(22000));
players.push_back(Player(18000));
```

i loop through it like this:

```
for (Player &player : players)
    std::cout << player._gold << endl;
```

Is there some way to name a starting index and make a full loop through players?
like

```
//pseudo
    for (Player &player : players, 2)
        std::cout << player._gold << endl;
```

would give

```
12000
32000
22000
18000
20000
10000
```

note that it starts from the 3rd element (index 2), and it doesnt stop at the end of the vector. Please give me some keyword or example how to do it the most simple way in c++.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an adaptor object, something like

```
template<class T>
class iterator_range
{
private:
    typename T::iterator begin_;
    typename T::iterator end_;
public:
    iterator_range(typename T::iterator b, typename T::iterator e):begin_(b),end_(e)
    {
    }
    typename T::iterator begin() const
    {
        return begin_;
    }

    typename T::iterator end() const
    {
        return end_;
    }
};
```

You can now do

```
for (Player &player : iterator_range(players.begin()+2,players.end()))
    std::cout << player._gold << endl;
```

Comment: I did. You need to implement a smarter iterator then, which should wrap around when the end of the vector is reached. I strongly suggest using two for cycles and the adaptor to get this behavior, I think it would be more readable.

Comment: Heh, I made an iterator that effectively concatenates two ranges: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0beec826cc1189a6 (untested, random_access is expected to be buggy still) Tests did nothing until I realized my start and end iterator are identical when the end of the second part is equal to the beginning of the first part >.<